# R - NA handing in a mann-whitney u test

Tags: r, statistics, na

I need to compute weighted Mann Whitney U test results a few hundred times. Each iteration involves is a two-sample test for differences between two groups. I can't figure out how to get the existing function to handle missing values without dynamically deleting cases.

The data for a few of the comparisons are [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18bSQrfkHZnaEzaIQZ6azYj4O1Vy7DDM0tGpv19cSbDc/edit?usp=sharing), in a data frame I call `dat`. All variables with numbers in this sheet are numeric in type.

Here's how I call the `sjstats::mannwhitney()` function:

```
mannwhitney(dat, measure1, group)
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "grp1.label", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
```

I suspect this is because of the missing value in the 212th observation of `measure1`. But wrapping the vector names in `na.omit()` or `!is.na()` don't address the problem, perhaps because doing so still results in a data frame where the number of non-NA values of `group` are greater than the number of non-NA values in `measure1`.

Any thoughts on how I could incorporate dynamic `NA` handling into the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what class your group column is, but if I do it like this:

```
library(sjstats)
dat = read.csv("question - Sheet1.csv")
str(dat)

'data.frame':   301 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ measure1 : num  2 1.6 2.2 2.7 1.8 1.8 4 4 3.9 -3.7 ...
 $ measure2 : num  0.9 0.1 0 0.4 -1 -1.3 2.1 0 -1.1 -3.9 ...
 $ measure3 : num  1.1 1.1 2.2 1.2 1.9 1.2 0 3 1.9 -3.8 ...
 $ measurre4: num  2 2 2 3 3 2 3 4 3 2.36 ...
 $ group    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I get:

```
mannwhitney(dat, measure1, group)
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "grp1.label", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
```

Factor your group:

```
dat$group = factor(dat$group)
mannwhitney(dat, measure1, group)

# Mann-Whitney-U-Test

Groups 1 = 0 (n = 110) | 2 = 1 (n = 190):
  U = 16913.000, W = 10808.000, p = 0.621, Z = 0.495
  effect-size r =   0.029
   rank-mean(1) = 153.75
   rank-mean(2) = 148.62
```

Reading the [code](https://rdrr.io/cran/sjstats/src/R/mwu.R), the bug comes from this:

```
labels <- sjlabelled::get_labels(grp, attr.only = F, values = NULL, 
        non.labelled = T)
```

If your group is numeric, it doesn't have attributes and hence you get no labels:

```
sjlabelled::get_labels(0:1)
NULL

sjlabelled::get_labels(factor(0:1))
[1] "0" "1"
```